# Where's the event reference ID in Sentry's hosted service getsentry.com?

Tags: django, sentry, raven

In my Django app's custom 500 handler, I can display the reference ID of the Sentry event using the template code `{{ request.sentry.id }}` -- but where do I see this ID listed in the getsentry.com reporting interface? All I can see is the timecode of the event and the event details and stacktrace etc. there without the reference ID.

NOTE: I'm using the free Sentry tier via a Heroku plug-in. It's Sentry version 6.0.0.

Comment: http://justcramer.com/2011/01/25/error-tracing-in-sentry/

Comment: @AamirAdnan - thanks. The search by ID function mentioned in this blog works great, but the ID does not show in the header of the exception for me as it does in the blog. All I get is e.g. "daily_operations.views in task_update_view_delegator
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
8 hours ago root"

Answer (score 0):

Just to fill in blanks, there's two things:

1. The Event ID (which you is either generated client side or retrieved from the server) can be looked up on the project's page using the search box (e.g. copy paste it into the search field). As of later versions (at the very least, 6.x+) all event IDs will always be present unless some throttling occurred.
2. The header only shows up if you enable raven.contrib.django.middleware.SentryMiddleware. This is actually recommend as it will guarantee the request object is available within any logging you do (that may have failed to explicitly include it).